# Age-associated neurodegenerative diseases

Tags: senescence

Age-associated neurodegenerative diseases encompass Alzheimer's Disease and Parkinson's Disease. What other neurodegenerative diseases could be described as age-associated? Multiple Sclerosis? Brain tumors? What might be the criteria for defining a disease as age-associated, specifically in the realm of neurobiology?

Answer (score 3):

> **Dementia with Lewy bodies (DLB):** It is characterized anatomically by the presence of Lewy bodies, clumps of alpha-synuclein and
>   ubiquitin protein in neurons, detectable in post-mortem brain
>   histology.[1] Lewy Body dementia affects 1.3 million individuals in
>   the United States alone.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dementia_with_Lewy_bodies

> **Binswanger disease** is a form of small vessel vascular dementia caused by damage to the white brain matter.[1] White matter atrophy
>   can be caused by many circumstances including chronic hypertension as
>   well as old age.[2] This disease is characterized by loss of memory
>   and intellectual function and by changes in mood. These changes
>   encompass what are known as executive functions of the brain.[3] It
>   usually presents between 54 and 66 years of age, and the first
>   symptoms are usually mental deterioration or stroke.[4]

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binswanger%27s_disease

To name the two with the highest prevalence after Alzheimer's and Parkinson's.

Comment: And what of MS, and a definition? Should age-association be defined by epidemiological studies or some other way?